# If else statement based on time

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a code on PHP where when the time between 6:00 am to 5:59 pm would be morning and will display a sun while 6:00 pm to 5:59 am would display the moon.

So far this is my code:

It always displays the moon image.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
    echo date("l, ");
    echo date("d F Y  ");


    echo date("G:i:sa  ");

    if (date('G'>17) && ( 'f' >=59) && ('sa' >=59))
    {
        echo $timeImage = "<img src=sun.png>";

    }

    else if(date('G'<6) && ('f' <= 01) && ('sa' <= 01 ))
    {
        echo $timeImage = "<img src=moon.png>";

    }


?>
```

Comment: `'f' >=59` Makes not much sense. In a numerical context it will come down to: `0 >= 59`

Comment: Your `if` statements don't make sense, conditions are completely messed up. Franz's approach is much nicer, and works :)

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to do this based on what I know :)  Well, thanks for the help  :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$seconds = time() - strtotime("today"); //seconds since midnight for now
$sec_a = 6*60*60; //seconds since midnight for 6am
$sec_b = 18*60*60; //seconds since midnight for 6pm

if($seconds >= $sec_a and $sec_b >= $seconds) //current seconds are larger than 6am or equal but smaller than 6pm
{
    echo "daytime";
} else {
    echo "nighttime";
}
```